# What species of bird of prey is this? Kestrel?

Tags: uk, bird-identification

Saw this bird on a post by a field in south east London, UK. We think it may be a kestrel from the colouring, but most kestrel photos online look more delicate than this one. Does anyone know what species this is?

[image: bird of prey on post in field]

Comment: Some kind of falcoon would also be my guess.

Answer (score 9):

I can't give a definitive answer, but it is *probably* a female kestrel, doing what kestrels do, which is to scan for small mammals either from a perch or on the wing.

The male's colours are more subdued.

From the colouring and my Collins *Complete Guide to British Birds* it could be a red kite or a merlin, but there are fewer than 2,000 breeding pairs of each of those, while there are over 50,000 pairs of kestrels, and they are a common sight. The red kite does not spend much time on the ground.

Comment: I agree. Red kites are surprisingly big and the tail is wrong ("rufous, deeply notched" says the book I have here). Even they don't have such clear markings on the back - nothing else (in the UK) does in those colours.

Comment: @ChrisH yes, the red kite does have notched tail visible in flight, but I don't know how it looks when folded.

Comment: My Collins is in the van, so I looked in my RSPB/Dorling Kindersley which has a nice clear picture perched (to which the caption I summarised points)

Comment: I've seen a few red kites near here but never perched - either in flight or on the ground. I think they prefer to scan the ground from the air rather than perches

Comment: The kite has a different head that is "longer" and more "eagle shaped", if that makes sense. IMHO this is clearly a kestrel, and a male one at that. I just read up on this a gain, and it seems the _male_ ones have the more prominent colour schemes, while the females are a bit more brownish.